# PHP get yesterday date from posting viariable date

Tags: php, date

I am trying to find a solution how to get yesterday from the date that will be sent by the form. Do you have any idea?
I

Comment: "yesterday" is relative to the current day, not the day the user entered. Do you mean "the day before the one the user entered"? If so then just Google how to subtract one day from a date using PHP. There should be plenty of examples

Comment: I know how to get the yesterday from current date but i have no idea how to get it from date that user send by form.

Comment: I'm looking for solution looking like `$Yesterday = date("Y-m-d",strtotime("-1 days"));` but replace date function with variable from posting date

Comment: Yesterday vs. Day before is like Wczoraj vs. Dzień wcześniej. For your problem, show us what did you try. You can just create DateTime object using input data and then subtract one day. https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's basics of [DateTime class](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php)

```php
<?php
$dateStr ='2021-01-01';
$dateObj = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', $dateStr);
$dateObj->sub(new DateInterval('P1D'));
var_dump($dateObj);
```

Of course, you should use your `$_POST` data instead of hardcoded value, also it may be required to adjust date format to your needs.

Finally, you can display modified date (with change of the format if required) like:

```php
echo $dateObj->format('d.m.Y');
```

Comment: Jeeeez! Of course, I meant the day before and not necessarily yesterday. Done. Dzięki;]

Answer (score 0):

yesterday delivers the day before the reference date with the time 00:00.

```
$userInput = '1967-04-23 14:04:28';
$date = date_create($userInput)->modify('yesterday');
echo $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
//1967-04-22 00:00:00
```

modify ('yesterday') is the same as

```
  ->modify('-1 Day')
  ->setTime(0,0)
```